# removing space between numbers from a text file

Tags: vim, sed, awk

I have the a text file with following data.I want to modify the second column as follows.The first row in the second column should be changed from `36 65 fb 5f 1a c1` to `0x3665fb5f1ac1` How do I do this using sed or awk or any other simple means (vim maybe.)

I want the first row to look like

```
0x5212cb03ca115ac0      0x3665fb5f1ac1

0x5212cb03ca115ac0      36 65 fb 5f 1a c1
0x5212cb03ca115cc0      36 65 fb 5f 1a c7
0x5212cb03ca115ea0      36 65 fb 5f 1a cd
0x5212cb03ca1160c0      36 65 fb 5f 1a d3
0x5212cb03ca1162a0      36 65 fb 5f 1a d9
0x5212cb03ca1164c0      36 65 fb 5f 1a de
0x5212cb03ca1166a0      36 65 fb 5f 1a e4
0x5212cb03ca1168a0      36 65 fb 5f 1a ea
0x5212cb03ca116aa0      36 65 fb 5f 1a f0
0x5212cb03ca116ca0      36 65 fb 5f 1a f6
0x5212cb03ca116ea0      36 65 fb 5f 1a fc
0x5212cb03ca1170a0      36 65 fb 5f 1b 02
0x5212cb03ca117280      36 65 fb 5f 1b 08
0x5212cb03ca117480      36 65 fb 5f 1b 0e
0x5212cb03ca117680      36 65 fb 5f 1b 14
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple awk solution...

```
awk '{ print $1"      0x"$2$3$4$5$6$7; }' input.txt
```

Comment: note that this line will change the separator between col1 and col2 into single space. also, fortunately your file has only 7 columns, not 700.

Comment: This is highly fragile solution. What if you have 2 additional columns in file some day?

Comment: I did say simple. =P OP is a beginner so I didn't feel it would be a great idea to complicate the command by throwing in complexity for a case they don't seem to need to worry about. As for the spaces, I put six originally but it looks like the Stack Overflow markdown removed the extras.

Answer (score 3):

If it's a one-off (which happens a dozen time during an average workday), I like to use Vim's block-visual mode, often in combination with `qq`...`q` to record quick macro.

Here, assuming starting point is start of file (`gg`):

**Update** Here's a demonstration using the optimization suggested in the comment:

#### 1. insert `0x` <kbd>`w`</kbd><kbd>C-v</kbd><kbd>G</kbd><kbd>I</kbd><kbd>`0x`</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>

#### 2. remove spaces  <kbd>`f`</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>C-v</kbd><kbd>G</kbd><kbd>`x`</kbd><kbd>`;.`</kbd><kbd>`;.`</kbd><kbd>`;.`</kbd><kbd>`;.`</kbd>

[image: animation of the steps]

***Job done!***

If you don't have `nostartofline` set, you can replace `G` with `1000j` or similar (I prefer `^VGw`  in this case).

1. <kbd>w</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>

   <sub>locate second columns of spaces</sub>
2. <kbd>^v</kbd><kbd>10000j</kbd>

   <sub>highlight the column in visual mode (use `G` instead of `1000j` if you have`nostartofline` set)</sub>
3. <kbd>x</kbd>

   <sub>drop it</sub>
4. <kbd>**;.**</kbd><kbd>**;.**</kbd><kbd>**;.**</kbd><kbd>**;.**</kbd>

   <sub>rinse & repeat</sub>

You'll see, once you get the hang of *block-visual mode* you'll start using it everywhere. Oh, and get <kbd>.</kbd> (and <kbd>;</kbd> and <kbd>,</kbd>) in your toolbox for quick, generic (motion) repeats!

---

Comment: Could a downvoter please comment? I'm pretty sure that for the one-off I can do this a **lot** quicker than any of the other answers

Comment: Instead of `10000j` or `ggw<c-v>Gw` you could do `set nostartofline` before executing anything. And then just do `G` to move to the bottom of the file. (Ends up with 1 less w)

Comment: @FDinoff I might end up starting to use that, because the cursor jumping is annoying. However, having to remember about 1 extra favourite setting is also not without burden. Thanks for reminding me, I need to reconsider this one.

Comment: In the spirit of "a picture speaks a thousand words" I've included a demonstration :)

Comment: Note that you can use `d<c-v>G` instead of `<c-v>Gd`. They're the same. However `dvj` and `vjd` are not the same: the first one excludes the last character.

Answer (score 2):

With substitutions:

```
:%s/\w\zs\s\ze\w//g
:%s/\s\+\zs/0x/
```

or all together:

```
:%s/\w\zs\s\ze\w//g|%s/\s\+\zs/0x/
```

Answer (score 2):

if you love to do it in vim:

```
%s/\s\s\zs\S.*/\='0x'.substitute(submatch(0),'\s',"","g")/
```

will do the job

Answer (score 1):

Vim solution

With nothing fancy just capture six groups of two hexadecimal digits and place them in the order you want.

```
:%s/\v(\x\x)\s(\x\x)\s(\x\x)\s(\x\x)\s(\x\x)\s(\x\x)$/0x\1\2\3\4\5\6
```

I get this as output

```
0x5212cb03ca115ac0      0x3665fb5f1ac1
0x5212cb03ca115cc0      0x3665fb5f1ac7
0x5212cb03ca115ea0      0x3665fb5f1acd
0x5212cb03ca1160c0      0x3665fb5f1ad3
0x5212cb03ca1162a0      0x3665fb5f1ad9
0x5212cb03ca1164c0      0x3665fb5f1ade
0x5212cb03ca1166a0      0x3665fb5f1ae4
0x5212cb03ca1168a0      0x3665fb5f1aea
0x5212cb03ca116aa0      0x3665fb5f1af0
0x5212cb03ca116ca0      0x3665fb5f1af6
0x5212cb03ca116ea0      0x3665fb5f1afc
0x5212cb03ca1170a0      0x3665fb5f1b02
0x5212cb03ca117280      0x3665fb5f1b08
0x5212cb03ca117480      0x3665fb5f1b0e
0x5212cb03ca117680      0x3665fb5f1b14
```

---

Since you had tabs in the separating the column instead of spaces you could just remove all spaces from the file.

```
:%s/ //g
```

And add `0x` after the first tab

```
:%s/\t/\t0x
```

Or all together

```
:%s/ //g|%s/\t/\t0x
```

Comment: I don't want to remove the space between two rows

Comment: @liv2hak Did you try it? It doesn't remove the space between them, it looks just like your expected output.

Comment: I did try.It does remove the space between them.and it doesn't remove the last space.
'0x5212cb03cca0590x003665fb66ba c2'

Comment: @liv2hak You have tabs in your file don't you? Thats the reason my thing didn't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this awk:

```
awk 'NR==1{for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) s=s$i; $0=$1 OFS "0x" s}1' OFS='\t' file
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\s/&0x/;s/\s//2g' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility with vim:

- Go to second column: <kbd>W</kbd>
- Select all columns: `<kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> <kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>$</kbd>
- Remove spaces inside selection: `:'<,'>s/\%V //g` (when you hit colon, `'<,'>` is automatically inserted because of visual mode, and in a pattern, `\%V` is a zero-width match but only inside visual area)
- Reselect : <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>
- Insert 0x: <kbd>I</kbd>`0x`<kbd>Esc</kbd>
- Save: <kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>

Total 23 keystrokes.